# Проблемы с наложением gif анимации на изображение с помощью pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pillow, gif

Мне нужно наложить готовую gif анимацию на картинку неважно какого формата(jpeg, png, gif и т.д) на определённые координаты. Я подумал что можно сделать так:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(...)
gif = Image.open(...)

img.paste(gif, (700, 320))

img.save(
     'test.gif',
     save_all=True,
     optimize=True,
     duration=100
)
```

Но из-за  тонкостей работы метода `paste()` наложить gif на изображение  невозможно.
Поэтому был бы благодарен каждому, кто поможет мне с этой проблемой.

Comment: Под «gif» вы имеете в виду анимацию или просто статичную gif-картинку?

Comment: Анимацию, внесу правки